# Auto initialize outlook add in when new email comes in Mailbox

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an app for Office 2013 (Outlook Add In) which will be used in Outlook Web App (OWA - Office 365) and I want to initialize the App as soon as a new email arrives in the mailbox.

Right now, We have to manually initialize the app. I tried Office.context.document,office.context.roamingSettings,office.context.mailbox and many more objects of **Office.js** but didn't succeeded at all.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail Add-ins cannot be initialized at the Mailbox level - they have to be initialized in the context of the selected message.  Even then, the app still needs to be "opened" by clicking the add-in header.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn893542.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much Eric. This is really very much helpful for me. Thanks a lot